# What errors do I need to fix to launch my Eclipse if it shows me an error asking me to check this log file?

Tags: java, eclipse

It shows me the message:

An error has occurred. See the log file

C:\Users\DELL\eclipse-workspace.metadata.log

Just before this, I'd recently installed new software for WindowBuilder.

[Here is the link to the .log text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GcgoMpA4bAJgtL-eGnD9dTakTK9Fa4wd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried seeing the log file?

Comment: Look in the log file and tell us what it says in there. Without that information we can't help you. Also tell us the versions of Eclipse and Java you are using.

Comment: I added a link to the text file in the question. It would be great if you could look into and tell me what all I need to fix. @greg-449 , Pavel Smirnov

Comment: @UditaAlawadhi Looks like you upgraded from Java 8 to Java 11 causing this. Does [running Eclipse with Java 8](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't Lauch it. Check the log file.